# My dGPU died but windows still shows it as working one

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, samsung-laptop

My laptop dGPU died probably, computer freeze while I was browsing, I was unable to start windows, then I just used safe mode and try to disable dGPU driver in device manager, then I deleted all related drivers and files of dGPU, but computer still trying to download driver for dGPU and it keeps turning the driver on, it shows cards information, also I can check dGPU information in AIDA64 with temperatures and looks nothing wrong with it, in addition it makes computer hot as if working.

Computer is Samsung Ativ Book 8 NP880Z5E-X01SE

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Most probably your GPU is working. Freezing and problems with Windows could be caused by some other issue. Updating or [reinstalling Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reinstall-windows-10-d8369486-3e33-7d9c-dccc-859e2b022fc7) (keeping files) could help fixing problems.

Comment: Actually I tried that many times, I tried even ubuntu, it keeps freezing.